# What are the Browsersync proxy settings needed for a dynamic site, i'm trying to run my app.js file but the page times out

Tags: node.js, proxy, gulp, browser-sync

```
    var bSync = done => {
        browserSync.init({

            proxy: {
                target: "localhost:" + 3000 + "/"
            },
            files: ['app.js'],
```

settings I'd tried previously

```
            // injectChanges: true,
            // proxy: '127.0.0.1:3000/',
            // host: 'localhost',
            // port: 3000
        });
        done();
    };
```

How can I get this to work - any ideas? I basically want to set up a gulp file that allows me to spin up my express server and then the routes and ejs files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work like this. The port and proxy were the same, but by switching the port to 3003 it worked without any issue. Tunnel meant i could connect other devices such as my phone while in production to view layouts etc which was pretty useful.

```
const bSync = () => {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'localhost:3000',
        port: 3003,
        online: true,
        tunnel: true
    });
};
```